# Blazor WASM: Unhandled exception Object of type T has a property matching the name, but it does not have [ParameterAttribute] applied

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly

I'm a bit stumped here because I do have the parameter attribute applied. I seem to be simply following [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/cascading-values-and-parameters?view=aspnetcore-5.0#cascadingparameter-attribute-1) in a one to one fashion.

Error message

```
Unhandled exception rendering component: Object of type 'Onero.Client.Features.CourseManager.CourseModelRegister' has a property matching the name 'HighSchoolRegistrationModelId', but it does not have [ParameterAttribute] applied.
```

Component hierarchy

```cs
//parent

<CascadingValue Value="HighSchoolRegistrationModelId">
    <CourseModelAddForm></CourseModelAddForm>
</CascadingValue>

@code {
    public long HighSchoolRegistrationModelId;
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
        HighSchoolRegistrationModelId = await CourseService.GetHighSchool();
    }
}

//middle component
@if (add)
{
    <CourseModelRegister HighSchoolRegistrationModelId="@HighSchoolRegistrationModelId"> 
    </CourseModelRegister>
}

@code {
    [CascadingParameter] 
    protected long HighSchoolRegistrationModelId { get; set; }
    private bool add = false;
    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        await base.OnParametersSetAsync();
    }
    private void ShowAddForm()
    {
        add = true;
    }
}

//Grandchild where error occurs

@code {
    [CascadingParameter] 
    protected long HighSchoolRegistrationModelId { get; set; }
   // rest of code omitted
}
```

Am I missing something? Perhaps this has to do with lifecycle management? I tried using OnInitialized as well as OnParametersSet.

Comment: I know it has been 2 months, have you had a chance to find an answer to this?

Comment: No, I vaguely recall seeing somewhere that there was an error with passing to grandchildren that needed to be fixed. I ended up just using ```Parameter``` and it worked well enough.

Comment: Did you finally handle it? I have the same problem, and in my case seems the DynamicComponent component (which is in between) is breaking the cascade

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty I have found the issue, I had the exact same situation, and its because I was passing value to the component's parameter and it was define as a [CascadingParameter], so it created a conflict.

So on this line:

> ```
> <CourseModelRegister HighSchoolRegistrationModelId="@HighSchoolRegistrationModelId"> 
> </CourseModelRegister>
> ```

You don't need to pass HighSchoolRegistrationModelId a value, because it will be filled by the [CascadingParameter]. In your case, you might need to make sure your middle component also has a [CascadingParameter] for the value to be passed to its children.

Comment: Taking the value out of that tag still resulted in the same error, sadly.